# NAND2 tpHL delay worst case

Tags: mosfet, cmos

We have a NAND2 gate and we want to find which input leads to the worst case tpHL delay.
I can understand that for input 00 and 11 is the best case to charge and discharge. I also understand that for tpLH delay the worst case is from 11->01 . But what is the worst case for tpHL 01->11 or 10->11 ?

picture for worst case for tpLH

[image]

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: what is the worst case for tpHL 01->11 or 10->11?

Comment: You have not marked your inputs, so I can't see which is which :( Also, include your motivation for "for tpLH delay the worst case is from 11->01".

Comment: for the above picture 1 is the first digit of 11 and the pulse 1->0 is the second. The worst case of tpLH delay = the bigger time. 11->01 is the wort case because Q1 is closed , Q3 open, Q4 is closed( so we have an internal capacity) so Q2 which is open must charge also the internal capacity.If for example we had 11->00 , then this is the best case ( smallest delay) because we have 2 open pMOS to charge the external capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is some finite rise time for your input signals, I think the worst case would be 00 to 11. You typically measure propagation delays from the 50% point of the inputs to the 50% point of the outputs, so the non-zero transition time of the inputs is important. You also have Miller effect coupling from the inputs to the outputs, which should not be ignored.

By the way, you have the body of Q3 tied to its source. In conventional, bulk CMOS technology the bodies of **all** NMOS transistors are usually tied to ground. Likewise, the bodies of all PMOS transistors would be tied to Vdd.

Comment: No 00 to 11 is the best case

Comment: @AdaselPomik But it seems you have completely ignored the body effect, Miller capacitance, and finite transition time on the inputs. Can you justify your claim that 00 to 11 is the fastest fall time of the output, taking the real characteristics of the transistors into account?

Comment: let me explain my thoughts:Let's say that C1=1pF and we want to charge it. For tpLH 11->00 we have 2 identically pMOS giving current to charge the capacitor. For 11->01 we have 1 pMOS to charge THE SAME capacitor. Same for 11->10. So logically 11->00 charges faster the capacitor, so the delay is the smallest. I want the same for tpHL, but confused with the internal capacity

Comment: You are correct that 11->00 is fastest for __tpLH__. However, the first comment you made to my answer mentioned 00->11 rather than 11->00, and the question is about __tpHL__ rather than tpLH. You certainly cannot assume that because 11->00 is fastest for pulling up that 00->11 will be fastest for pulling down. In one case the transistors are in parallel, in the other they are in series.

Answer (score 0):

I read this in my VLSI course. Let me just quote from that book:

[image]

Figure 9.6 shows a 2-input NAND gate annotated with diffusion parasitics. Consider the falling output transition occurring when one input held a stable 1 value and the other rises from 0 to 1.

If input B rises last, node x will initially be at VDD – Vt ~ VDD because it was pulled up
through the nMOS transistor on input A. The Elmore delay is (R/2)(2C) + R(6C) = 7RC

On the other hand, if input A rises last, node x will initially be at 0 V because it
was discharged through the nMOS transistor on input B. No charge must be delivered to
node x, so the Elmore delay is simply R(6C) = 6RC

In general, we deﬁne the outer input to be the input closer to the supply rail (e.g., B)
and the inner input to be the input closer to the output (e.g., A). The parasitic delay is
smallest when the inner input switches last because the intermediate nodes have already
been discharged. Therefore, if one signal is known to arrive later than the others, the gate is fastest when that signal is connected to the inner input.

page 331 of [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321547748)

Comment: You made a critical assumption that is not part of the original question. You said "if one signal is known to arrive later than the others" but that's not how the question was asked. I believe your conclusion about the __best__ case is correct but you have ignored what is truly the __worst__ (as opposed to __worse__) case for output fall time.

Comment: well, according to his figure, it seems like one input is already at '1' while other input has a falling transition.

Comment: Yes, that's the worst case for tpLH as the figure is clearly marked. However, the question is about the worst case for __tpHL__, not tpLH. While Weste & Harris is a good book for the student it necessarily simplifies the real world considerably. As another example, the two PMOS would typically share a drain diffusion, giving a total estimated capacitance of 4C at the output rather than 6C.

Comment: Yes, I assumed similar scenario for tpHL, where one input is already at '1' and other one will have a low-high transition. But you might be right about that book.

Answer (score 0):

OP probably understands (or is past caring) already but I will explain for everyone else.

It's hard to understand the inputs so I will clarify something:

- when I say 'A' I am talking about the first number which controls Q2 and Q4
- when I say 'B' I am talk about the second number which controls Q1 and Q3

**In the first case 01->11**

- At the start: Q2 and Q3 are open, the rest are closed. C1 and C2
  are charged to VDD (logic 1, high).
- A changes from 0 to 1; this closes Q2 and opens Q4, Q3 and Q4 are open so C1 and C2 can discharge to ground (logic 0, low).

**In the second case 10->11**

- At the start: Q1 and Q4 are open, the rest are closed. C1 is charged to VDD and C2 is discharged to GND.
- B changes from 0 to 1; this closes Q1 and opens Q3, Q3 and Q4 are open so C1 can discharge to ground.

**Answer**

In the first case C1 and C2 needed to be discharged as apposed the second case where only C1 is discharged *therefore* case one (01->11) is the worst High to Low switching case (tpHL).